# Can you knockout a gene specifically in the dorsal root ganglion in adult mammals?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

Since the dorsal root ganglion is so small, would that be easier than the entire body?

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE - do you know how to make a whole body gene knockout? Or perhaps a tissue specific knockout? Those might be better questions to ask because then you'll understand why the size of a particular tissue or organ that matters, but rather the gene expression of a particular organ. There are a number of review articles on gene knockout techniques, I would recommend you read one of those and then post a more specific question that would be more helpful.

Comment: what is the exact problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 2):

It requires two genetic constructs to create a conditional KO organism. One parent with a transgene that expresses a DNA recombinase (such as Cre) after the promoter of a gene that is ONLY expressed in your tissue of interest. The other parent contains a modified gene of interest to be removed in the presence of said DNA recombinase but is fully functional otherwise.

**Therefore, the ability to target a Knockout to a specific tissue is dependent on identifying a gene that is only expressed in the tissue of interest.**

It is actually easier to create a whole animal KO, but because gene products can have different functions temporally in development and in different tissues, a whole animal KO may be lethal, whereas removing it in a specific tissue may not be and allows study of the effects of said removal.

Thus, if your gene of interest were lethal when removed from whole organism, AND you know of a gene that is only expressed in the DRG, you would have incentive to see if a CKO animal could be made.

A brief search on Cre Lox technology will bring up 1000's of images and articles.
Here is [one](http://www.scq.ubc.ca/targeting-your-dna-with-the-crelox-system/) and a nice illustration:

[image]

Comment: @Hamham just a note on this technique... this technique works well but you can control the timing of the knockout... that is, if you want to make some mice and then induce the expression of the Cre enzyme in the adult animal (if you have an inducible-Cre system) you can do that; however, if the Cre is expressed in embryos during development then the gene will be missing from birth and may have a different phenotype compared to if the gene knockout is induced in an adult animal.

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh Can the "if you want to make some mice" part be switched to "if you catch some wild mice"? Aka, Unlike the picture above, I can just use any mouse without transgenic parents and induce the gene knockout in it...? Thanks!

Comment: @Hamham No, this wouldn't be successful with wild mice - you have to use laboratory mouse strains for which DNA sequence information is known. As indicated above, the idea is to breed one strain of mouse that has loxP sites flanking the gene of interest to another strain that expresses a tissue/cell-specific Cre recombinase enzyme. There are other technologies to do knockout (like CRISPR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR ); but again, this is to begin breeding mice, not to knockout a gene in an adult mouse